# why NoSuchMethodError was thrown in springboot with RedisTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I'm confused by this error,I debug the code, trace the redisTemplate object,which owned the delete method. I hope someone give me some advice,I'm much obliged!
[image]

[image]

relationship between two RedisTemplates like below:
[image]
[image]
com.xdd.redis.cluster.service.RedisTemplate extends com.xdd.redis.cluster.service.SingleRedisTemplate extends org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate
stack information as below:

```
2021-08-18 17:05:29,495 ERROR http-nio-9801-exec-3 c.x.h.w.c.GlobalExceptionHandler 121 globalException ---- Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.xdd.redis.cluster.service.RedisTemplate.delete(Ljava/lang/Object;)Jorg.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.xdd.redis.cluster.service.RedisTemplate.delete(Ljava/lang/Object;)J
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.xdd.components.gray.filter.GrayFilter.doFilter(GrayFilter.java:39)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:450)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.xdd.redis.cluster.service.RedisTemplate.delete(Ljava/lang/Object;)J
at com.xdd.shiro.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:111)
at com.xdd.shiro.controller.LoginController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$242e2c13.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
at com.xdd.shiro.controller.LoginController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da2ee076.login()
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
... 69 common frames omitted

here is maven dependency tree

```html
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ xdd-helper-web-api ---
[INFO] com.xdd.helper:xdd-helper-web-api:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.alibaba.boot:nacos-config-spring-boot-starter:jar:0.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.alibaba.nacos:nacos-spring-context:jar:0.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.alibaba.nacos:nacos-client:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.alibaba.nacos:nacos-common:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.alibaba.nacos:nacos-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.alibaba.spring:spring-context-support:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.alibaba.boot:nacos-config-spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:0.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.alibaba.boot:nacos-spring-boot-base:jar:0.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.36:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.16:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.4:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.dubbo:dubbo:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-CR2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.50.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.7.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.sgroschupf:zkclient:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.shiro:shiro-manager-provider:jar:4.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.xdd.boss:xdd-boss-remote:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.axet:kaptcha:jar:0.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.jhlabs:filters:jar:2.0.235:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.alibaba:fastjson:jar:1.2.61:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.xdd.components:redis-api:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.xdd.components:redis-common:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:2.1.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:2.1.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.1.16.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.9.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-spring:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-lang:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-crypto-hash:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.shiro:shiro-crypto-core:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-crypto-cipher:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-core:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-config-ogdl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.shiro:shiro-event:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.shiro:shiro-web:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.owasp.encoder:encoder:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-ehcache:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.shiro:shiro-cache:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.6.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.dubboclub:cat-dubbo-monitor:jar:0.1.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.dianping.cat:cat-core:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.unidal.framework:foundation-service:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.unidal.framework:web-framework:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.unidal.framework:dal-jdbc:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.dianping.cat:cat-client:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.24:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.xiaoymin:swagger-bootstrap-ui:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.logback-extensions:logback-ext-spring:jar:0.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- com.xdd.helper:xdd-helper-bff:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.xdd.helper:xdd-helper-remote:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.xdd.components:dubbo-gray-core:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.xdd.file:xdd-file-manager-remote:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.xdd.account:xdd-account-remote:jar:3.0.4-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.xdd.components:xdd-domain:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.xdd.components:xdd-property-editor-util:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.caucho:hessian:jar:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.xdd.components.monitor:health-doctor-http:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] +- com.xdd:xdd-utils:jar:2.4.12-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.jxls:jxls-core:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.4:provided
```

Comment: Using incompatible versions of libraries. You are using Spring Boot so I suggest to stick with the starters instead of trying to figure out dependencies and versions yourself.

Comment: Actually，first probably thought occor to my mind is various version libraries.But i checked many times, it is not the main reason,so this is really confuse me.

Comment: It is the main reason else this error wouldnt occur.

Comment: i add the maven dependency tree,only one redis component contains in my project.you can check it.